# Google Site Search search button glyphicon

Tags: javascript, css, google-api

How did they modify the search button text to an icon on the below jsfiddle?

I have exact same code/tags (except cx param) on my page but the search button text says "Search" and has an X icon next to it. I haven't found any setting in the GSS control panel that allows this kind of modification to the button.

```js
// Make sure in jsFiddle you have selected option onLoad.
(function() {
  var cx = '017643444788069204610:4gvhea_mvga'; // Insert your own Custom Search Engine ID here
  var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
  gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
      '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid blue;">
    Area 1 (for example a sidebar)
    <gcse:searchbox></gcse:searchbox>
</div>

<div style="border: 1px solid red;">
    Area 2 (for example main area of the page)
    <gcse:searchresults></gcse:searchresults>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you just need to read this https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/1721914?hl=en&ref_topic=1723767 more carefully expecially the section Look and feel and Customize the search box

Comment: @LucaFilosofi if you don't mind can you point out the specific section where the button modification is explained. because i've been looking through the same set of docs you provided for past one hour and haven't found anything that specifically deals about the button text/icon.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902393/how-to-replace-google-custom-search-engines-magnifying-glass-with-a-button-that

Comment: go there: https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4513783?hl=en then click on the link "Control Panel". once you are in add your site then on the left follow the instruction of the link above...

Comment: @LucaFilosofi in GSS Control Panel, changing the "Theme" to "Default" automatically changes the button content to search icon instead of search text. If you can add this as answer I will gladly accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

go there: https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4513783?hl=en then click on the link "Control Panel".

Once you are in, add your site, then look on the left site and follow this instructions:

[How to replace google custom search engine's magnifying glass with a button that says "search"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902393/how-to-replace-google-custom-search-engines-magnifying-glass-with-a-button-that)